# Using Cadastral data - how can I count number of Lots in a given Suburb based on my calculated field AreaOfLot

Tags: qgis, layers, count

I make us of my local Councils Cadastral data, and I'm looking to identify all properties over a certain area within the surrounding suburbs.

I have loaded in Layers for "**Lot**" and "**Suburb**" and added a new calculated field "**AreaOfLot**" to the Lot layer.  This works fine, each lot label shows Lot number and Area (in Acres).

What I can't work out is how to add to the Suburb label a field showing X number of lots in that suburb that are over a given value of Y acres.

Any help or pointers greatly accepted and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use the field calculator to add a field called *suburb* to layer "lot" which is set to the suburb that the lot is in.

`array_first(overlay_intersects(layer:='suburb',expression:="suburb"))`

2. Use the field calculator to add a field called, for example, *countLotsGT200* to layer "lot" to hold the count of lots (X) that are over the required value (Y) e.g. 200:

`count("AreaOfLot",group_by:="suburb",filter:="AreaofLot" > 200)`

3. Add a label to layer "suburb" with this:

`array_first(overlay_intersects('lot',"CountLotsGT200"))`

OR

Just do step 1 and use this for the label on layer "suburb":

```
array_first(overlay_intersects(layer:='lot',expression:= count("AreaOfLot",group_by:="suburb",filter:="AreaofLot" > 200)))
```